# Dynamics for sets related to Brownian motion: zero set, fast points

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, brownian-motion

For sets like the Cantor set, we have preserving maps (eg. the shift-maps and conjugates to it) that allows us to study dynamical quantities such as invariant measure and entropy. I am wondering if we have proved/disproved of the existence of such maps for the zero set of BM and its fast points:

$$
\lim_{h \searrow 0} \frac{|B(t+h) - B(t)|}{\sqrt{2 h \ln(1/h)}} =1.
$$

I was hoping that somehow the Strong-Markov property will give self-similar structure to these sets and some natural measure preserving map. At least for the zero-set we have that it is homeomorphic to the cantor set, so I suppose that would give some dynamics by precomposing.

**Ergodicity on unit circle**

We know that Brownian motion itself is not ergodic on the real line but it is in compact spaces such as the unit circle. So maybe there is something interesting we can say for these sets on the unit circle.

Comment: To make it easier to understand this, can you formulate a precise mathematical question like "does there exist a map..."?